# What would a program in Ruby look like if it creates hashes and saves those hashes in another file?

Tags: ruby, save

I'm really new to programming in Ruby, and I can't find anything on the internet related to programs that create hashes and stores them in another file. What would the code to a .rb file that does that look like?

Answer (score 1):

Usually *Ruby hashes* aren't written directly to a file. We use serialization formats such as JSON or YAML so that the file can be read by other programming languages and tools besides Ruby also.

Let's use JSON as an example since it's the most common. We can read/write from JSON easily

```
require 'json'

path = "path.json"
hsh = { a: 1, b: 2 }

# Write to the file

File.open(path, "w") do |file|
  file.write hsh.to_json
end

# Read from the file

hsh2 = JSON.parse(File.read(path))

# let's print them out for inspection

print hsh
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2}

print hsh2
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

As you can see, the hashes are technically not *identical*, and that's because JSON doesn't have a *symbol* data type (YAML does, by the way). But they do contain the same data.

---

Note, in response to your comment about the goal here. What you're asking for is a *human readable data serialization format* and fortunately JSON and YAML are both human-readable, and are used all the time for this purpose.

To use YAML, just `require 'yaml'` and replace the `to_json` and `JSON.parse` calls in the previous example with `to_yaml` and `YAML.load` respectively. YAML is very human-readable by default, and I would search for a tutorial on its syntax to get familiar with it.

`to_json` is by default not so readable, since it dumps everything on the same line, but you can use `JSON.pretty_generate(hsh)` instead and it will make things a lot nicer.

Comment: I was referring to a interface where the person using the file could fill in data for a list of hashes. My goal is to make a program that lets people fill out information on books they have with information such as book title, genre, and the author.

Comment: @Noodle54 edited answer, is that the info you're looking for?

Comment: You can use `to_yaml` or `JSON.pretty_generate` to create an initial file structure and then it can be passed around for manual editing by the other people, before you load it back into the program.

Comment: Both YAML and JSON support nested arrays / hashes / etc so you can feel free to use more complex data structures

Comment: yes it was what I was looking for. I think I might just work on the program user input myself, since my goal is for the user of the program to create a hash within the program.

Answer (score 1):

For nearly any object x, but certainly including a Hash, you can use

```
s=Marshal.dump(x)
```

to create an internal representation of the object, which has the type `String`, and safe it to a file. If you later load the String back from the file and do a

```
x=Marshal.load(s)
```

you can recreate your object. I prefer this over the JSON approach described by Max Pleaner in his excellent answer, because (if you apply it to your Hash) it works, even if the Hash values are instances of arbitrary classes you have created, where there is no standard formatting offered by JSON. Marshal even saves/restores the "frozen" state of an object, which is something JSON can't do.

On the other side, the drawback of Marshal is that you need to recreate the data with a Ruby program, while JSON is a standardized format which can be processed by other applications. Even more, the Marshal-format is not guaranteed to be compatible between different major Ruby versions, so if this is an issue for you, don't use it.

Yet another transfer format is YAML; the concept is the same as with Marshal, but it is a bit slower, and like with JSON, it does not work for arbitrary types inside your Hash, unless you provide suitable transfer methods by yourself. Like JSON, YAML can be read from other applications and, for humans, I find it a bit easier to read than JSON:

```
require 'yaml'
s = YAML.dump(x)
```

restoring with:

```
x = YAML.load(s)
```